# Watson conversation - Condition response not working as expected

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

I am getting @sys-number as an input and my condiyion is ->
If  input number is between 18 & 30, provide a response else a different response.

But, Watson does not recognize the 2nd condition. Details are attached

[Watson Dialog screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8sDM.png)

Please help.

P.S: I have also tried to separate this condition as 2 different nodes and that does not work, as well.

Comment: Your second condition should be an `OR`, not `AND`. But realistically you could just set the second one to `True`.

Comment: shoot!! Silly of me to have missed that.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple response conditions for your need and only one node is needed. check out the images, hope it helps.

1. [Changes in Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txc3G.png)
2. [Response from Try it Out window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y1j6.png)